how to lock an object temporarily on aws s3
I'm working on a project that has some json files stored on s3. I need to add some kind of locking mechanism so multiple processes wait for each other when changing the files.
Each process does something like:

lock s3://bucket/file.json
download s3://bucket/file.json to /tmp/file.json
process and modify /tmp/file.json (takes a few seconds up to a minute)
upload the /tmp/file.json to s3://bucket/file.json
unlock s3://bucket/file.json

I'd like to make sure that only one process is working on a file at a time, and if another process already locked a file, then the next process trying to work on the same file waits until the file is unlocked (because the processes are adding/removing elements to a list in the file)
It's possible that more than one process can be blocked (waiting for the same object) at the same time, if this happens then it doesn't matter which, but only one of the blocked processes should be unblocked when the file is unlocked, and the other blocked processes wait, until it's unlocked again.
How could I achieve this using boto3 in python?
The current (old) implementation only uses put_object to upload the files and delete_object to remove them (until now there wasn't a concurrency possible)

I would probably use something like a DynamoDB table to manage locking, something made to work in real time. You might be able to do it with S3, but you could end up with race conditions and lost data. S3 objects are immutable, cannot be edited, so you're constantly uploading new versions of the object. If bucket versioning is on you may be paying for many, many versions of that object.
